# How to avoid a terminal prompt in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a simple Java program that asks a series of questions. At the end I ask the user if they would like to continue with the program or quit. If they say yes, the program asks them the same questions as before. This works, but as soon as they as asked the questions the program seems to stop. This is the function that I am calling. IS it because I don't have anything at the end of the if statement? I'm new to Java and just trying to understand this sequence.

```
void doMore(){

        System.out.print("Do you want to do anything else? : Yes|No ");
        String answer = keyboard.nextLine();

        if(answer.equals("YES") || answer.equals("yes")|| answer.equals("Y") || answer.equals("y")){
            showInstructions();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Thank you for using the lego manager. Please come back soon!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: you need a loop somewhere, but since you have not posted a complete example, hard to say

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with the doMore() method, so the issue is likely where you invoke that method from. What does the rest of the code do? We can't keep guessing which is why you need the MRE as suggested in the first comment. Providing a piece of code out of context does not help.

Comment: maybe I'm not using the correct term but this is what happens after the show instructions method is called 
name@imac-pro cs-501 % 2 
After that the program doesn't run any more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, simplify your conditionals by using `answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")`. This will cover all permutations of "yes" (i.e. "yes", "YES", "yES", etc.).

Then, as @Aurous suggested, you need to use a `while` or `do-while` loop to enclose your code. For I can see, you don't need the `doMore` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = null; // Needs to be declared outside the do-while because it is used outside of it (scope is confined to inside curly braces)
    do {
        System.out.print("Do you want to do anything else? : Yes|No ");
        answer = keyboard.next(); // You DO NOT want to use nextLine()
        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
            showInstructions();
        }
    } while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no") && !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));

    keyboard.close(); // always close your I/O resources
    System.out.println("Thank you for using the lego manager. Please come back soon!");
    System.exit(0);
}

public static void showInstructions() {...}
```

This will break out of the loop if you type "no" or "n", but if you type some other string value, it will continue to loop. I don't like this particular approach, but it will "work" for what you need. That said, it will only call the method if the entered string value is either "yes" or "y".

Also, notice that I use `next()` instead of `nextLine()`. This is very important because you are comparing for equality and not with `startsWith()` or some other method. The function `nextLine()` is more suited for cases when the inputted string is more than a word (words separated by whitespaces).

Lastly, never forget to close your I/O resources.

Answer (score 2):

If you could provide more of the code that would be great, however one suggestion I'd give is placing a while loop around the chunk of where you ask the user questions, something like.

```
do{
// questions
} while(answer !=no)
System.out.println("Thank you for using the lego manager. Please come back soon!");
System.exit(0);
```